# Oracle SQL Select Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a system which has a stakeholders.  The system could have either a Business Data owner, a Technical Data owner, both, or neither.  There is a SystemToOwner relationship table which holds the id's of the system and a stakeholder, and specifies the role of the stakeholder (Business vs Technical).  Role is actually a foreign key which resides in a table holding various roles.  I'm looking to select some information from multiple tables and put it in a report.  I have a column for the business stakeholder and the technical stakeholder for each system. My issue is that with the current code if there are both a business and technical data owner I get two rows, one with the business filled out and the tech blank and one with the tech filled out and the business blank.  How can I get this to be one entry?

```
SELECT  system.name "System"
,system.definition "Definition"
,CASE WHEN role.name LIKE 'Business%' THEN nvl2(stk.last_name,stk.last_name || ', ' || stk.first_name, null)ELSE NULL END  "Bus Data Steward"
,CASE WHEN role.name LIKE 'Technical%' THEN nvl2(stk.last_name,stk.last_name || ', ' || stk.first_name, null) ELSE NULL END "Tech Data Steward"
FROM
    system
LEFT JOIN  relationship ON system.element_id = relationship.system
LEFT JOIN  stk ON relationship.stakeholder = stk.element_id
LEFT JOIN  role on relationship.role = role.element_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join the role tables in twice, using subqueries that filter roles to either one or the other:

```
SELECT * FROM
system
LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT relationship.system, stk.last_name, stk.firstname, role.name 
  FROM relationship
    INNER JOIN  stk ON relationship.stakeholder = stk.element_id
    INNER JOIN  role on relationship.role = role.element_id WHERE role.name like 'Business%'
) as role_biz 
ON system.element_id = role_biz.system

LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT relationship.system, stk.last_name, stk.firstname, role.name 
  FROM relationship
    INNER JOIN  stk ON relationship.stakeholder = stk.element_id
    INNER JOIN  role on relationship.role = role.element_id WHERE role.name like 'Technical%'
) as role_tec 
ON system.element_id = role_tec.system
```

Comment: For me this results in an ORA-00905 missing keyword error.  There are actually a lot more columns involved with this but even if I try it with this small set in the question/your answer I still get it.

Comment: I'm assuming that is because of the 'as' keyword there?  Without it I get a table non-existent error so maybe I'm wrong.